# Angular 4 - ngFor not working and no error in console

Tags: angular

I need to build a chart with data that I consumed on API, first I builded in HTML and ok it's working fine, when I try to show the API values by `console.log` it's working fine as well, but when I put *ngFor on my HTML the output is nothing and no error on console.

Take a look at my code:

```js
public method1(): void {
    this.FileService
      .getKnowledge(this.iditens)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.itens = response;
      });
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let item of itens">
    <h6>{{heatmap.itens[0].file}}</h6>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><div>{{heatmap.itens[0].file}}</div><span>{{heatmap.itens[0].file}}</span></li>
      </ul>
      <span>{{heatmap.itens[0].file}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "peopleSkills" is an array, so you need to access first element before you can go to "skill".

Try this:

```
{{groupSkill.person.peopleSkills[0].skill.knowledge.knowledgeName}}
```

Comment: Did not work "/ ... Where is the right place to put the ngFor?

Comment: @ESC It's hard to see what those classes in your template do. If I were you, I'd begin by removing all the classes, and trying to print simple things at first. Start by groupSkill.person.peopleName and check if you see that on screen, and keep going one step at a time.

Comment: =/ not working and not showing up the erro on console.

Answer (score 0):

peopleSkills not typeof object you can't use peopleSkills. with any property you need index of peopleSkills as the same peopleSkills[0]. you can't use to access as peopleSkills.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: The problem this here `{{groupSkill.person.peopleSkills.skill.knowledge.knowledgeName}} `
you need change it 
`{{groupSkill.person.peopleSkills[0].skill....}}`

Comment: you can use
 `<div class="row" *ngFor="let groupSkill of squad.squadPeople">
 <div *ngFor="let peopleSkill of groupSkill">
{{peopleSkill.skill.knowledge.knowledgeName}}
</div>
</div>
`

Comment: Not working, console error TypeError: Cannot read property 'squadPeople' of undefined

Answer (score -1):

`peopleSkills` isn't Object it's an array. So access your `peopleSkills` with array index.

```
{{groupSkill.person.peopleSkills[0].skill.knowledge.knowledgeName}}
```

Or you can make you api like this

```
{
   "squadPeople":[
      {
         "person":{
            "peopleName":"User Name",
            "peopleSkills":{
               {
                  "percentValue":"90",
                  "skill":{
                     "skillName":"MariaDB",
                     "knowledgeId":3,
                     "knowledge":{
                        "knowledgeName":"Banco de dados"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure what you are suggesting in the "Or" part doesn't work. You can't have "peopleSkills" : { { ...  } } . You'd need a property like this: "peopleSkills" : { "0" : { ... }  } . More info - https://www.sitepoint.com/back-to-basics-javascript-object-syntax/

Comment: @dexter I'm damn sure. I was convert array to object. and this object don't have  index 0  in `peopleSkills` .

Comment: @dexter see this definition from ECMASCRIPT docoumetioan  [An object is a collection of properties and has a single prototype object. The prototype may be the null value.](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-object) .  0 index don't need for this

Comment: @dexter ` peopleSkills` look like single name value pair. So I've suggested to convert array to object. that's all.